# sorting positive integers in unsorted array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

This was given to me in a recent programming interview. I am given an unsorted array of integers with negative and positive values, and required to sort them but only for the positive values. I was wondering what some of your solutions might be without using Google.

After getting home I found **Arrays.sort()** sorts the array in ascending order but I am not sure how to output to new array with only the positive values, as this was a requirement. I am able to print them by just printing if they are greater than -1, but how would I input them into new array without having to loop through the array and count the number of positive values to get the size of the new array, instantiate new array, then loop again to add them to new array.. This solution seems not optimal, is there a better way ?

*the output needs to be a new array with only positive values, that is sorted*

**Below is what I have so far:**

```
  import java.util.Arrays;


    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
            int[] unsorted = {
                -3, 95, -4, 20, 5, 6, 8
            };
            int[] sorted = unsorted;
            Arrays.sort(sorted);

            for (int s: sorted) {
                if (s > -1)
                    System.out.println(s);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What you are saying sounds like filtering + sorting. "output to new array with only the positive values". Do you want a new array with only positive values, that is sorted. Or did you mean you want a new array that has both negative and positive values, but only the positive values are sorted.

Comment: The problem is underspecified. What does _"sort them but only for the positive values"_ mean?

Comment: It sounds to me like the intent of this interview question is to check to see if you really understand the process of sorting. This is relevant in an interview because writing custom sort logic is something that happens fairly often in many programming positions.

Comment: I want Do you want a new array with only positive values, that is sorted

Comment: So you want to discard all negative values? This is in fact filtering with sorting.

Comment: There are multiple approaches to this, and it's hard to tell which is the right one without know the exact interview question. As in what is allowed. Can you use a list? Are you not allowed to use lists? Etc.

Comment: If given the choice of languages I would use C# and say `unsorted.Where(i => i > 0).OrderBy(i => i).ToArray()`

Comment: I believe I was allowed to do anything all I was given was a method with the array that needs to be sorted, and a return statement where I would need to return the new filtered and sorted array..

Comment: @chuckj That would be equivalent to iterating the array, discarding any negative numbers. Then, using the standard sort logic.

Comment: @chuckj had to use Java lol :/

Comment: The most efficient way, timewise, is to loop through the array and stick the non negative values in a list, sort the list and convert to an array. If you need to save memory instead, sorting first and then finding the first non-negative number will save the space taken by the list. Finally you could copy the positive side of the sorted array into a new array with `Arrays.copy`.

Comment: @EduardoDennis When I usually ask these questions like this I give the interviewee the choice of languages as I believe a programmer can learn a language quickly, learning to be a good coder takes considerable time. I am trying to determine coding ability, not language proficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try putting the data in a [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), making sure to only deal with the positive values:

```
int[] unsorted = { -3, 95, -4, 20, 5, 6, 8 };

PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>(unsorted.length);

for (int a : unsorted) {
    if (a > 0)
        q.add(a);
}

while (!q.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(q.poll());
}
```

```
5
6
8
20
95
```

This approach will be *O(nlog(n))* where *n* is the number of positive integers in the array. Sorting the entire array, by contrast, will be *O(nlog(n))* where *n* is the length of the entire array.

Comment: Where are you getting O(nlog(n))? The Javadoc for Priority Queue says _Implementation note: this implementation provides O(log(n)) time for the enqueing and dequeing methods_.

Comment: You repeat the _O(log(n))_ of the priority queue _n_ times giving _O(n log(n))_. This is just a disguised heap sort.

Answer (score 1):

What if you performed a binary search for `0` on your sorted array, and then only printed values from that point on? `Arrays.binarySearch()` returns the index that `0` WOULD be at if it doesn't find `0` in your array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int[] unsorted = {
            -3, 95, -4, 20, 5, 6, 8
        };
        int[] sorted = unsorted;
        Arrays.sort(sorted);

        int breakingPoint = Arrays.binarySearch(sorted, 0);
        for (int i = breakingPoint; i < sorted.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(sorted[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This has problem of `n` being the size of the original array instead of `n` being the number of positive integers for the `O(n log n)` of the sort. Not a big deal for small number of negative numbers but a big deal for large arrays.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you're right. It would be more efficient to reduce n for sorting, which is O(nlog(n)) and let it be large for checking-for-positives, which is O(n). I'll leave this answer, though, since you provided some valuable insight.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your own sorting algorithm. I would use a modified quicksort in an interview:

1-pick 0 to be the pivot for the first recursive call and put all numbers that are equal or bigger than 0 on the right array

2-Only call quicksort on the right array for the first recursive call,for the other recursive calls,use a random pivot.

3- When concatenating,remove the first 0 you find.

Fast(nlogN),and you can do it even in the same array,or return a new one.

Comment: Actually you don't need step (3) as the first step already tells you where to stop. This also sounds like the answer the interviewer was going for.

Comment: mmm,yup,he can keep concatenating as long as the pivot is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the [Collection.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) must be stable, so if you have use a comparator that says that all negative numbers are equal, but for positive numbers does what you'd expect, you'd have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate the array
2. For each positive value, store the position and value into two arrays
3. Sort the value array

Comment: Why do you need step (4)? Isn't the value array the array you want?

Comment: Because negative ones are also important :-) why are they stated?

Comment: answer fixed. although, the priority queue was really the best answer

Answer (score 0):

Creating a list just for the dynamic aspect would mean potentially resizing the array multiple times during the removal process.

I elected instead to use `Arrays.copyOf` to resize the array after I knew how big it needed to be.

The first thing I did was filter out the negatives:

```
int[] unsorted = {
    -3, 95, -4, 20, 5, 6, 8
};

int[] positives = new int[unsorted.length]; //It can only be as big as unsorted.

int i = 0, j = 0;

for (; i < unsorted.length; i++) {
    if (unsorted[i] >= 0)
        positives[j++] = unsorted[i];
}
```

Then, I resize the array:

```
positives = Arrays.copyOf(positives, j);
```

Finally, I sort it:

```
Arrays.sort(positives);
```

Here is an [IDEOne.com demo](http://ideone.com/EwSWMI)

Comment: Please leave a comment on your decision to down-vote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

simple separate the positive numbers - it needs one copy

```
List<Integer> positives = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Integer number: unsorted) {
    if (number > 0) {
        positives.add(number);
    }
}
```

and then sort them.

```
Collections.sort(positives);
```